# Flutter Firestore document path null check

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I have a `FutureBuilder` which gets data from `FireStore`.

Sometimes the document path I'm passing is null since this is a very large database and some old documents are deleted.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future:
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(documentSnapshot['vid'].path).get(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Text("Something went wrong");
    }
    if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
      return const Text("Document doesn't exist");
    } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data =
          snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            data['name'],
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          Text(
            data['address'],
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 11,
                color: hexStringToColor('636567')),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines: 1,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
    return const Text("Loading...");
  },
)
```

the `documentSnapshot['vid].path` is sometimes `null`.

I need to check if `path` is `null` and only if that was not `null` I should proceed with `FutureBuilder`.

I couldn't check that with a if condition.

Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the value of `documentSnapshot['vid'].path` before going on with the `FutureBuilder`, then you can just check if it is `null` before the `FutureBuilder`.

Example:

```
documentSnapshot['vid'].path == null? Text('Not Found!') : FutureBuilder(...)
```